# Creating text summary using NLP

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am in middle of applying NLP to the set of comments that I have received from my data. These comments are stored in one column. I have cleaned them altogether stored them in a list. There are no stop words, special characters etc. Now I want to create a summary from this text. What could be the best method to do that? I have already failed myself with heapq, so I dont want any solution around that.

My clean text is stored in list named : `clean_text_summary` and it looks like this :

```
clean_text_summary = ['You are so bad - I hate your product','I am going to deregister','You are frauds'....]
```

I need to get most common things that people have talked about as a summary.

Comment: You can look into text summarization using SpaCy methods. Here is an example https://jcharistech.wordpress.com/2018/12/31/text-summarization-using-spacy-and-python/

Comment: Already tried that.. and I got my mistake as well. All of sentences were getting read as one. So the algorithm was not able to create a summary out of it. But thanks for your response!!

Comment: Perhaps you could post your spacy-based script, with some sample text, the output you got, and the output you expected. It could be a simple script fix, or it might be a data problem, or it could be that you've got your expectations too high, and what you need is mechanical turk.